# Using Sqoop/Hive, how can I save foreign key information into HDFS with the other data?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hdfs, sqoop

Supposing we have tables in Mysql which are normalized by primary and foreign keys. Once data stored into HDFS we will lose the foreign key constraint's information. How could I keep this information in HDFS ?

Comment: When data is imported into HDFS, How do we loose foreign key constraint's information? Once data is imported all it is in flat data model. From HDFS is it extracted into HIVE/PIG/? ,

Comment: That's it .. data will be in a flat data model and we no longer know which column represents a foreign key !

Comment: HDFS is not an RDBMS. It doesn't have primary keys, foreign keys, or contraints.

Comment: @Andrew this is why I am looking for something which can keep this information (constraint) in HDFS.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  A FK constraint is only relevant for inserts. If you're sqooping data from MySql to HDFS, those constraints, even if you could create them, would have no meaning.

Comment: @Andrew It's not for creation, I want to keep a trace for the schema table. For example, I have table "worker" with a column "id" which is a FK of another table. In HDFS, we cannot know that "id" corresponds to another table.

Comment: Normalized data are not recommended in Hive/Impala environment. The relationships between the tables will have to be resolved by JOINs during query time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually possible to maintain the FK constraint in Hive. But as you might be aware, once the data is imported you should be able to join the data on the columns to extract whatever you want.